# Angular 2 referencing external DOM elements

Tags: angular

I would like to use Angular 2 for augmenting an existing aspx page. The page has a couple of fields that contain json data, and I would like to be able to use that json inside my Angular 2 components.

For example, I have an index.html that looks like this:

```
<my-ng-app></my-ng-app>
<input type="hidden" id="student" value="{name: 'bill'}" />
```

Is there any way I can get the value from that hidden field into my ng2 components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use direct JavaScript to do it:

```
let student = document.getElementById("student").value;
```

If you need to parse the value into an object, `JSON.parse(student)` will do it for you

Or you can use `Document` from `@angular/platform-browser` like so:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.document.querySelector("#student").value;
}
```